# Is there any way to run a capybara server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am looking for a way to get my cucumber test with selenium and capybara to skip the startup of the server on each run of the test. Is there a way to let is startup in the background and stay running and attach to it on each test run?

Comment: Don't be afraid to give me credit for the answer if it worked for you. If it didn't work let me know that too.

Comment: The answer you posted completely disappeared from this post.  I am in the middle of trying to get Spork implemented ... hopefully it will work ... I will post the results here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Spork? https://github.com/timcharper/spork

It basically forks a copy of your server each time you run your tests but doesn't require it to restart the whole Rails environment every time so saves you huge amounts of time if you have a large Rails app.